# Displaying an amount of objects on to the screen and positioning

Tags: python, pygame

I am following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python#comments
And I am trying to reduce the amount of badgers drawn to the screen from the part where the badgers are drawn. It looks to me as the `random.randint(50,430)` draws a number of badgers between 50 and 430. But i would like a smaller number say 5-9 badgers drawn on the screen. I would also like to know the position of where the badgers are comming from. I would like it so the badgers fall from the air. How do i do this?

```
if badtimer==0:
        badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)])
        badtimer=100-(badtimer1*2)
        if badtimer1>=35:
            badtimer1=35
        else:
            badtimer1+=5
    index=0
    for badguy in badguys:
        if badguy[0]<-64:
            badguys.pop(index)
        badguy[0]-=7
        index+=1
    for badguy in badguys:
        screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
```

here is the full code:

```
# 1 - Import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import random

# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]
acc=[0,0]
arrows=[]
badtimer=100
badtimer1=0
badguys=[[640,100]]
healthvalue=194
pygame.mixer.init()

# 3 - Load image
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png")
arrow = pygame.image.load("resources/images/bullet.png")
badguyimg1 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy.png")
badguyimg=badguyimg1
healthbar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/healthbar.png")

health = pygame.image.load("resources/images/health.png")
gameover = pygame.image.load("resources/images/gameover.png")
youwin = pygame.image.load("resources/images/youwin.png")
# 3.1 - Load audio
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/explode.wav")
enemy = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/enemy.wav")
shoot = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/shoot.wav")
hit.set_volume(0.05)
enemy.set_volume(0.05)
shoot.set_volume(0.05)
pygame.mixer.music.load('resources/audio/moonlight.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.25)

# 4 - keep looping through
running = 1
exitcode = 0
while running:
    badtimer-=1
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the player on the screen at X:100, Y:100
    for x in range(0, int(width/grass.get_width()+1)):
        for y in range(0, int(height/grass.get_height()+1)):
            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,345 ))
    # 6.1 - Set player position and rotation
    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
    playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360-angle*57.29)
    playerpos1 = (playerpos[0]-playerrot.get_rect().width/2, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height/2)
    screen.blit(playerrot, playerpos1) 
    # 6.2 - Draw arrows
    for bullet in arrows:
        index=0
        velx=math.cos(bullet[0])*10
        vely=math.sin(bullet[0])*10
        bullet[1]+=velx
        bullet[2]+=vely
        if bullet[1]<-64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2]<-64 or bullet[2]>480:
            arrows.pop(index)
        index+=1
        for projectile in arrows:
            arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
            screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
    # 6.3 - Draw badgers
    if badtimer==0:
        badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)])
        badtimer=100-(badtimer1*2)
        if badtimer1>=35:
            badtimer1=35
        else:
            badtimer1+=5
    index=0
    for badguy in badguys:
        if badguy[0]<-64:
            badguys.pop(index)
        badguy[0]-=7
        # 6.3.1 - Attack castle
        badrect=pygame.Rect(badguyimg.get_rect())
        badrect.top=badguy[1]
        badrect.left=badguy[0]
        if badrect.left<64:
            hit.play()
            healthvalue -= random.randint(5,20)
            badguys.pop(index)
        #6.3.2 - Check for collisions
        index1=0
        for bullet in arrows:
            bullrect=pygame.Rect(arrow.get_rect())
            bullrect.left=bullet[1]
            bullrect.top=bullet[2]
            if badrect.colliderect(bullrect):
                enemy.play()
                acc[0]+=1
                badguys.pop(index)
                arrows.pop(index1)
            index1+=1
        # 6.3.3 - Next bad guy
        index+=1
    for badguy in badguys:
        screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
    # 6.4 - Draw clock
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    survivedtext = font.render(str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/60000)+":"+str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000%60).zfill(2), True, (0,0,0))
    textRect = survivedtext.get_rect()
    textRect.topright=[635,5]
    screen.blit(survivedtext, textRect)
    # 6.5 - Draw health bar
    screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))
    for health1 in range(healthvalue):
        screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_d:
                keys[3]=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            shoot.play()
            position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            acc[1]+=1
            arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos1[1]+32])

    # 9 - Move player
    if keys[0]:
        playerpos[1]-=5
    elif keys[2]:
        playerpos[1]+=5
    if keys[1]:
        playerpos[0]-=5
    elif keys[3]:
        playerpos[0]+=5

    #10 - Win/Lose check
    if pygame.time.get_ticks()>=90000:
        running=0
        exitcode=1
    if healthvalue<=0:
        running=0
        exitcode=0
    if acc[1]!=0:
        accuracy=acc[0]*1.0/acc[1]*100
    else:
        accuracy=0
# 11 - Win/lose display        
if exitcode==0:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (255,0,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(gameover, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
else:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (0,255,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(youwin, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Same question (same wording, same code), other user: [Displaying an amount of objects on to the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346318/displaying-an-amount-of-objects-on-to-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 bager is added each time badtimer==0. The line badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)]) adds a new badguy at that location (x=640, y=random.randint(50,430)]) on the screen.

If you want to change the number of bad guys loaded you have to change this part of the code

```
if badtimer==0:
    badguys.append([640, random.randint(50,430)])
    badtimer=100-(badtimer1*2)
    if badtimer1>=35:
        badtimer1=35
    else:
        badtimer1+=5
```

There are two varables that the spawning on badguys depends on **badtimer** and **badtimer1**.

**badtimer1** is used to increase the rate at which badguys are spawned as the game goes on (Technically it increments each time a badguy is spawned).

**badtimer** is used to actually create the badguys every so offten which is decremented each loop.

---

To have them fall from the sky you need to change their original starting point and their  updating.

```
badguys.append([random.randint(50,590), 0])
```

and Updating

```
for badguy in badguys:
    if badguy[1]<520:
        badguys.pop(index)
    badguy[1]+=7 //You can change this number if it is too fast
```

Comment: When i apply your changes i get an empty list error, its not falling from the sky